# Is there a pre/post $apply hook in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom-events, hook

I wish to run a callback function whenever `$apply` is called on a scope. Is there a pre/post `$apply` hook or some event that I can bind to, to achieve this?

Comment: $apply gets run a lot more then you might think, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I have another scope in an `iframe` which shares a service with the parent document, so I want changes to be equally applied on both ends.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why You need that, but there is no pre/post `$apply` event. 
I guess you call `scope.$apply` in your code, so you can emit event there before and after. Generally you should avoid calling `scope.$apply`, exception is when you update model outside Angular context (for example in signalR event)

Comment: I thought this might be the best way to synchronize scopes in two different frames, but it looks like I will have to find another way.